# jquery ui slider -reverse starting and ending position

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a vertical slider.Is there any way that I can make the handler work from top to bottom?

```
$( ".dragscrollbar" ).slider({
            orientation: "vertical"
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
$( ".dragscrollbar" ).slider({ value: 100 });
```

If you changed the max value just change were it says 100 up there to be your new max value